# Qiwi как подтвердить платёж

Tags: php, qiwi

На сайте Qiwi Api https://developer.qiwi.com/ru/... php#create есть код для получения статуса. С помощью композера я скачал себе библиотеку киви с гитхаба(https://github.com/QIWI-API/bill-payments-php-sdk). Вставил секретный ключ, и решил сделать пробный перевод на 1 руб. Статус стал оплачен. Скопировал id перевода(в киви это billid) и вставил его тоже. Открыл страница, а она грузится 1 мин и вылетает ошибка что превышен тайм-аут в 60 сек. Обращался в тех. поддержку так и не помогли. Надеюсь вы помогите?
Код:

```
require 'qiwi/vendor/autoload.php';

const NEW_SECRET_KEY = 'eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiUDJQIiwiZGF0YSI6eyJwYXlpbl9tZXJjaGFudF9zaXRlX3VpZCI6Im11YzJsdC0wMCIsInVzZXJfaWQiOiI3OTg3OTY1ODY0NCIsInNlY3JldCI6ImY1Mzk1OTUyNjk3MjY3NzhjODU4YTJkZmYxMjQwYjNlMjJiYzg4ODJjOWUyOWM0NTFkMjUzMjU5*****';

/** @var \Qiwi\Api\BillPayments $billPayments */
$billPayments->key = NEW_SECRET_KEY;




$billPayments = new Qiwi\Api\BillPayments(NEW_SECRET_KEY);

$billId = 'f70a81a9-6ea0-489a-8260-88######';

/** @var \Qiwi\Api\BillPayments $billPayments */
$response = $billPayments->getBillInfo($billId);

print_r($response);
```

Comment: Тоже столкнулся с этой проблемой, как решил?

Comment: Если еще надо могу предоставить код

Comment: Да, предоставте, буду очень признателен.Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот код рабочий

```
$urla = "https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js";
// Создаём запрос
$ch = curl_init();
// Настройки запроса
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urla);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Отправка и декодинг ответа
$data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), $assoc=true);
// Закрытие запроса
curl_close($ch);

$billid = $_GET['hash'];
  $url = 'https://api.qiwi.com/partner/bill/v1/bills/' . $billid;

  $siteid = 'muc2lt-00';
    $date = date("YmdHis");
    $car = 100;
      $datec = $date + $car;
      $user = R::findOne("bill", "billid = ?", array($billid));
       if( $user )
       {
$curl = curl_init(); // создаем экземпляр curl

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'accept: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer         eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiUDJQIiwiZGF0YSI6eyJwYXlpbl9tZXJjaGFudF9zaXRlX3VpZCI6Im11YzJsdC0    wMCIsInVzZXJfa+++++++'
));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $token = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);

     $staat = $token["status"];
     $mon = $token["amount"];
     $result = substr($staat["changedDateTime"], 0,                              
 strpos($staat["changedDateTime"], "."));
          $ggloаa = str_replace('-', '', $result);
      $ggloаas = str_replace('T', '', $ggloаa);
      $ggloа = str_replace(':', '', $ggloаas);
 if($staat["value"] == 'PAID')
 {
     
     if($mon["currency"] == 'RUB')
 {
     if($user['paid'] == 0 and $user['id_user'] == $pe){
     $pek = R::load('bill', $user);
     $pek->money = $mon["value"];     
     $pek->date = $ggloа;    
     $pek->paid = 1;     
      R::store($pek);
              $peka = R::load('users', $pe);
     $peka->money = $per['money'] + $mon["value"];    
      R::store($peka);
      header('Location: http://keeppixel.ml/');
     }else{
         header('Location: http://keeppixel.ml/');
     }
 }
     if($mon["currency"] == 'KZT')
 {
     if($user['paid'] == 0 and $user['id_user'] == $pe){
         $KZT = $data["Valute"]["KZT"]["Value"]; 
      $KZT_in_RUB = $mon["value"] * $KZT;
     $pek = R::load('bill', $user);
     $pek->money = $KZT_in_RUB;   
     $pek->date = $ggloа;    
     $pek->paid = 1;     
      R::store($pek);
      $peka = R::load('users', $pe);
     $peka->money = $per['money'] + $KZT_in_RUB;      
      R::store($peka);
      header('Location: http://keeppixel.ml/');
     }else{
         header('Location: http://keeppixel.ml/');
     }
 }
     }else{
         header('Location: http://keeppixel.ml/');
     }
 
 if($staat["value"] == 'WAITING')
 {
     echo 'wating';
 }
   }
   else{
         header('Location: http://keeppixel.ml/');
     }
     }else{
         header('Location: http://keeppixel.ml/');
     }
     }else{
         header('Location: http://keeppixel.ml/');
     }
```

Тут есть встроенная конвертация